# For loop display numbers in label

Tags: java

I'm having to learn Java, and at the moment just testing a few things out at home. I'm stuck at what would appear to be a easy task and that is display all numbers from a text box after splitting the string.

I can only get the last number to appear. My code is below any help for a Java newbie would be appreciated.

```
private void btnSubmitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        String lottoNumbers = txtLotteryNumbers.getText();
        String[] temp;
        String delimiter = " ";
        temp = lottoNumbers.split(delimiter);

        for(int i = 0; i<temp.length; i++)
        {
        lblNumbersEntered.setText("You entered numbers" + " " + temp[i]);
        txtNumbersEntered.setText("You entered numbers" + " " + temp[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The for loop is running, but runs **immediately** and so all  you see is the last answer. The solution: look up and use a Swing Timer, not a for-loop.

Comment: You have to use a SinwgWorker

Comment: Instead print it in a console.

Comment: @BilalDja: no indeed not. There's no long running process that requires direct use of a background thread. **Again** a Swing Timer is all that is needed, and is much easier and straight forward to use than a SwingWorker.

Comment: Hi @HovercraftFullOfEels as stated in question, just started learning Java today, so never even heard of swing timer, thanks for heads up. I think its going to be a big learning curve.

Comment: Well java has a lot of concepts, let the GUI stuff to the next level (just a Tips)